# Выделение запятыми слова "несомненно"

Tags: запятые

В правилах написано, что в качестве вводного слова выделяется запятыми, когда его можно спокойно убрать из предложения, заменить на "конечно", "разумеется". Но «несомненно» может быть членом предложения. В таком случае постановка знаков препинания неуместна. В разных контекстах выступает частью составного сказуемого или обстоятельством, присоединяемым к определению. Например: **такое отношение несомненно приведёт неопытного педагога к конфликтам**.
Мой вопрос: а как понять, почувствовать эту разницу? Ведь в приведенном примере тоже можно без потери смысла убрать это слово или заменить на "конечно". Но тут это часть сказуемого почему-то и запятыми не выделяется...

Answer (score 1):

1. **Проверка** путем исключения вводного слова из состава предложения или замены его синонимом представляется мне решением формальными и некорректным (оно скорее подходит для обучения младших школьников, когда они только начинают знакомиться с темой). В действительности определение статуса вводного слова — это **задача не из простых**, и она связана с анализом структуры конкретного предложения, а также отчасти это может быть авторским решением.
2. В качестве исходного ориентира можно использовать **Справочник по пунктуации**, где даются **парные варианты** для вводных слов http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_484

**НЕСОМНЕННО,** вводное слово.  **Несомненно**, песенка грустная.  **Несомненно,** она обладала хорошей памятью. Не смешивать с употреблением в роли члена предложения. Положим, такая победа над смертью не может быть достигнута сразу, что совершенно **несомнЕнно**.

Варианты здесь приведены **беспроигрышные**. В начале предложения "несомненно" практически всегда является вводным словом (его удобно обособить). Во втором примере слово является сказуемым.

3. **В середине предложения** варианты возможны, хотя вводное значение слова более частотное. В частности,  варианты имеют место в приведенном предложении, что видно **из его структуры  и расстановки ударений.**

(1) Такое отношение несомнЕнно (наверняка, обязательно) приведёт / неопытного педагога к конфлИктам.

(2) Такое отношение, несомненно (= скорее всего),  приведЁт / неопытного педагога к конфлИктам.

4. Но в некоторых  случаях обстоятельственное значение может быть **единственным,** например:

Все эти процессы, относящиеся к группе оперативных, **несомненно** важны, но, как отмечалось на конференции, имеют значение прежде всего для самого ИТ-отдела.

Состав нашей команды был **несомненно** сильнее, чем у других.

А здесь имеет место выбор автора (**логическое выделение слова**): Если латынь ― это изобретение средневекового фальсификатора, то он несомнЕнно должен был знать сравнительную грамматику не только романских языков, но и всей индоевропейской семьи языков в целом.

Comment: Хм. А как вам такой вариант: "Кто из этих двух обладает хорошей памятью, молодой человек или девушка?" — "Несомненно он**а** обладает!" Тут нужна запятая?

Comment: Плохой у  вас вариант  (вернее, набор слов, а не вариант). Так не надо говорить, а то вас примут за  англичанина.  Правильный ответ: Она, несомненно.

Comment: Чем принципиально отличается "Несомненно она!" от "Конечно нет!"?

Comment: Вы же сами ударение поставили на "она".  Можете подчеркнуть, конечно, свою уверенность, если вам голосовых связок не жалко и ситуация позволяет: НесомнЕнно она!

Answer (score 0):

Всё дело в логическом ударении. Если автору нужно его поставить на *несомненно*, то автор это слово считает членом предложения. В таком виде оно скорее заменимо не на 'конечно', а на 'наверняка'. Сравните:

- Такое отношение, конечно, приведёт неопытного педагога к конфликтам.
- Такое отношение наверняка приведёт неопытного педагога к конфликтам.